# How to get value from Struct Array in hive

Tags: hive

TABLE STRUCTURE

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS LocationTable
(
USER_ID BIGINT,
NAME STRING,
STATE STRUCT < DISTRICT ARRAY < ID:BIGINT, NAME:STRING > >
)
```

My Query is :

```
SELECT user_id, name,
district.pos as district_pos,
district.name as district_name,
FROM
locationtable,
locationtable.state.district district
WHERE user_id = '58'
```

Its throwing the below error.

```
Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:20 cannot recognize input near '.' 'district' 'district' in table source
```

where am doing wrong ?

Comment: Array syntax is: `ARRAY<data_type>`, not  `ARRAY < ID:BIGINT, NAME:STRING >`, this looks like struct

Answer (score 0):

Use `explode`

```
select 
     user_id,
     name,
     state.district.ID as district_pos,
     state.district.NAME as district_name
from
   locationtable 
   lateral view explode(STATE) exploded_table as state;
```